# Ignore anything that does not meed a condition in a Conditional Split

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have records that can meet one of three conditions and continue the flow.  For those records that do not meet any of those conditions, I want to ignore them, throw them away so to speak.  Right now, they are falling to my Error Output, which I'd rather that did not do.

These are employee records, that I am checking for certain conditions and if nothing needs to be done, ignore.  After awhile, I could have several thousand records that need no processing and end up in the Error Output even though they are not an error.

How do you specify that final "bucket"?  If nothing else matches do this, or actually do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

On a conditional split any rows that don't meet one of the conditions will fall into the default output.  You can either choose to attach this output to a subsequent transformation/destination, or if you want to discard rows that don't meet the given criteria you can just not attach this output to any additional components.  If you really want to ensure that you capture  rows which don't meet any of the first three conditions, then add an additional condition with a statement that always returns true (i.e.  1==1) and since rows are directed to the first condition they meet only rows which don't qualify for the first three conditions will fall here, although this behavior would be the same as just using the default output for these rows.

Comment: I agree, the rows should fall through to the default output, but they are going to the Error Output instead.

Comment: Have you redirected the rows falling into the error output and confirmed there are no errors by using the ErrorCode and ErrorColumn columns?